# Disable Macbook monitor with external screen AND open lid

Tags: macbook-pro, screen, touch-id

Since my MacBook 2016 i5 built-in screen starts to flicker, I want to reduce the use by linking an external screen and fully disable the built-in screen.

However, to use the macbook Touch ID button, the lid needs to remain open.

How do I do this?

Comment: Is your Mac M1 processor by chance? Also https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/56839/5472 may have some hints

Comment: It's a 2016 i5 processor.